# How to display occurrences of number in array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, frequency

Hi i want to display occurrences of number in int[] array. I found that many people try to ask similar question but their array is String. Here is my work pick 10 random number from 10-25 and print it 100 times, display the occurrences of number. For example:

12 15 16 17 20 14 24 21 22 15
10 12 16 24 23 14 23 12 11 10

Frequency of 10 is: 2
Frequency of 11 is: 1
Frequency of 12 is: 3
And so on

```
public void pickRandomNo(int[] a) {
        printHeader();
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array[i] = 10 + randomGenerator.nextInt((25 - 10) + 1);
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        } System.out.println("");
      }      
    }

 public void displayOccurences() {
        ArrayList arrlist = new ArrayList();       
        arrlist.add(array);
        int freq = Collections.frequency(arrlist, 10);
        System.out.println("Frequency of 10 is: " + freq);      
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, for your `displayOccurences` method you could just do:

```
int freq = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), 10);
```

Or you could do it the old fashioned way and iterate through:

```
int freq = 0;
for(final int v : array)
    if(v == 10)
        freq++;
```

Or if you are using Java 8, you could try something like this:

```
int freq = Arrays.asList(array).stream().filter(i -> i.equals(10) || i == 10).count();
```

Comment: Did u store int[] array into array arrlist??/

Comment: @KienAlexanderNguyen `Arrays.asList(T[] array)` is the exact same thing as doing `new ArrayList<T>(array)`

Comment: I used debug, arraylist has only 10 value for us to assign, how can i expand it to 100

Answer (score 0):

Guava MultiSet based solution:

```
    HashMultiset<Integer> ms = HashMultiset.create();
    for(int i : a) {
        ms.add(i);
    }
    for(Entry<Integer> e : ms.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getElement() + " - " + e.getCount());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be sure you count the entire range of the array.  I had a similar issue where I was displaying all occurances of each temperature in a very large ArrayList I used this static method to display a table.

```
public static void displayOccurances(ArrayList<Integer> tempsList){
    //  get min and max for looping
    int i = Collections.min(tempsList);
    int maxTemp = Collections.max(tempsList);

    // Table Headings
    System.out.println("Frequency of each teperature");
    System.out.printf("%4s%9s%n", "TEMP", "COUNT");
    System.out.printf("%4s%9s%n", "====", "=====");

    // Loop through arraylist to display occurrences
    while (i <= maxTemp) {
        System.out.printf("%4s%9s%n", i, Collections.frequency(tempsList, i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

I will refactor it to a general array for you here.

```
public static void displayOccurances(Integer[] array){
    //  get min and max for looping
    int i = Collections.min(array);
    int maxInt = Collections.max(array);

    // Table Headings
    System.out.println("Frequency of each Integer");
    System.out.printf("%3s%9s%n", "INT", "COUNT");
    System.out.printf("%3s%9s%n", "===", "=====");

    // Loop through array to display occurrences
    while (i <= maxInt) {
        System.out.printf("%3s%9s%n", i, Collections.frequency(array, i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

This was my first answer, so sorry if my code doesn't display correctly.

The idea is that you identify your highest and lowest occurrences using the Java Collections Class (which you will need to import).  Starting at the low range you check each integer in the range for the number of occurrences, again using the Collections Class.

If you don't want to display 0 occurrences, just put an if around the printf inside the loop, like so

```
// Loop through arraylist to display occurances
    while (i <= maxTemp) {
        if (Collections.frequency(tempsList, i) > 0){
            System.out.printf("%4s%9s%n", i, Collections.frequency(tempsList, i));                
        }
        i++;
    }
```